# Why does Intellij debugger always stop in jar file (specifically PlainSocketImpl.acceptSocket())

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

For some reason, everytime I run my project on debug mode my intellij pauses the execution on this specific jar file and only continues if I pause the execution, mute breakpoints and resume execution.

Due to this issue I am not able to use the debug mode of intellij since if I unmute my breakpoints the execution only pauses in PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept() and not the breakpoints in my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij IDEA Breakpoints stop in JARs instead of source code of my project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992181/intellij-idea-breakpoints-stop-in-jars-instead-of-source-code-of-my-project)

Comment: Any exception breakpoints configured?

Comment: The solution provided in the above question did not solve my problem.

Comment: And I have not configured any exception breakpoints.